# meaning of "should have out-grown"

Tags: meaning

> Hitler’s confidant Albert Speer certainly believed the prejudice was a remnant from his Austro-Hungarian days **which Hitler should have out-grown.**
> <sub>Source: [*Hitler: Study of a Revolutionary?*
>    By Martyn Housden](https://books.google.com/books?id=gfuFAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA174&ots=OGV9ajpNNF&dq=%22Hitler%E2%80%99s%20confidant%20Albert%20Speer%22%20%22certainly%20believed%20the%20prejudice%22&pg=PA174#v=onepage&q=%22Hitler%E2%80%99s%20confidant%20Albert%20Speer%22%20%22certainly%20believed%20the%20prejudice%22&f=false)</sub>

How do you understand this sentence? To which noun is "which" connected? I think it’s connected to "prejudice". Can we conclude from the sentence that Speer thinks that Hitler should have gotten rid of the prejudice?

Comment: "got rid of" is not quite the same as "outgrow." At [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/outgrow): **outgrow** (*v.*) To lose or discard in the course of maturation: _She outgrew her youthful idealism_. "Get rid of" is more abrupt; "outgrow" is more gradual.

Comment: over-simplistically… he should have out-grown his prejudice, like a 52 year-old 'girl' should have out-grown her desire to wear pink roller-skates to school.

Answer (score 1):

> Hitler’s confidant, Albert Speer, certainly believed the prejudice was a remnant from his Austro-Hungarian days which Hitler should have out-grown.

Let's rewrite this sentence. We can remove a lot of unnecessary words to keep the sentence simple.

> <strike>Hitler’s confidant</strike> Albert Speer <strike>certainly</strike> believed <strike>the</strike> **Hitler's** prejudice <strike>was a remnant</strike> **remained** from his Austro-Hungarian days which Hitler should have out-grown.

A second rewrite to make the meaning clearer.

> Albert Speer believed two things. One, that Hitler's prejudice came from his Austro-Hungarian days, and Two, that Hitler should have out-grown his Austro-Hungarian days.

The meaning of "Out grow his Austro-Hungarian days" means that Albert Speer believes that Hitler's prejudice is a silly and immature result of his time in Austria/Hungary, and that as Hitler grows older and matures, he should change his mind on the matter, and stop being prejudiced.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I am not able to fully understand the part "Hitler should have out-grown his Austro-Hungarian days".

Comment: I edited my answer. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yes, your edit helped me with understanding. May be my doubts about this sentence stemmed from the fact that I could not comprehend the core of Speer's statement which I found buck-passing. He was Nazi as Hitler and so the moralistic tone seemed to me a little bit false.

Comment: According to the [wikipedia page on Albert Speer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Speer), he was known as "the Nazi who said sorry", he took moral responsibility at the [Nuremberg Trials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuremberg_trials) and he claimed ignorance of the Holocaust. Unless he is a liar, this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to the latter two questions is "yes".

"Hitler’s confidant Albert Speer certainly believed the prejudice was a remnant from his Austro-Hungarian days which Hitler should have out-grown."

Speer believed that Hitler should have outgrown his prejudice, which was a remnant from his Austro-Hungarian days.